# The given expression is never of the provided type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, types

I have an abstract class, let's call it `Base`. I then have a number of classes inheriting from `Base`, like this example:

```
public class Actual : Base
{
    ...
}
```

I want to determine if the actual type (not the abstract base) at runtime is a specific type (using the [is keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)). It is done in a method which accepts any class, which inherits from `Base`:

```
public void Method(Base input)
{
    if (input.GetType() is Actual)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This gives me a warning in Visual Studio (2019) stating that:

> CS0184: The given expession is never of the provided ('Actual') type

Why is this? The `Actual` class is only one of many, which inherits from `Base`. So it is in no way given, that it will be of that type at runtime...

**Note:**

I have tried to follow `Actual` by using `Ctrl` + `Click` and I have done the same for `Base`. In both cases I end up at the expected classes. Also, there are no duplicate class names in any of the assemblies which is involved in the solution.

Comment: Probably the `Actual` in `input is Actual` is not the actual class you think.

Comment: @CodeCaster or `Base`

Comment: @CodeCaster what do you mean by that? If I Ctrl + Click the `Actual` in the if statement, it goes to the class which inherits from `Base`... The same goes if I do it for `Base`.

Comment: Do the same then in `Base` in `Actual`'s implementation. The type system in C# and VS works, one of the classes involved must not the one you think it is.

Comment: @InBetween I have done that as well. It takes me to the exact same implementation of `Base` as when I follow the track from the `Method(Base input)`.

Comment: The info on [the CS0184](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0184) says it does check if that type could be of type checked. I wonder if you have several namespaces with similar class names and you are getting it wrong. Consider editing your question and adding a [mcve], you are missing the `Base` class definition and the namespaces involved.

Comment: I would suggest to fully name the classes (namespace + class name) in `Method` to make sure they are what you think they are

Comment: As stated, there I no other classes, with matching (or even similar) names. I have checked a lot. I would like to provide a more complete example (and will try to do so), but it quickly ends up quite messy, if I include everything.

Comment: Assume this is not a bug in the compiler, but that the problem is in your code. Your simplified example does not reproduce the behavior you describe. For all we know, in the actual code, earlier in the method there's code like `if (input is Actual) return;`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I missed something when making the simplified example, which accidentally happened to fix my bug. In my original code i wrote `if (input.GetType() is Actual)`. And the `GetType()` should not be there (it seems) when using the `is` keyword.

Comment: `GetType` returns `TypeInfo`, not the type. Remove `.GetType`. The `is` operator is a compile time construct but `GetType` uses reflection which is a runtime construct. Check the return type of `GetType` and you will see the compiler is right, there's no way `TypeInfo` is ever going to inherit from `Actual`. (sorry it's `Type` not typeinfo but same thing)

Comment: You're looking for IsAssignableFrom then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the advice from CodeCaster, we should use `input is Actual` instead of `input.GetType() is Actual`.

Like the following code:

```
public void Method(Base input)
        {
            if (input is Actual)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("yes");
            }
        }
```

Also, you can use it like:

```
        Program p = new Program();
        Actual act = new Actual();
        p.Method(act);
```

Finally, you will get output "yes".